# NextJS Typescript getInitialProps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using NextJS 'latest' with TypeScript to query the token out of the URL; however, when doing so I get back undefined. I am using the `getInitialProps` method to do so. Here is what my url is:

URL: `http://localhost:3000/change-password/37cf81bb-dawd-4a41-af5d-3e712270d0ef`

I want to grab the dynamic token variable: `37cf81bb-dawd-4a41-af5d-3e712270d0ef`

the file path is like so
**change-password/[token].tsx**

and here is the logic:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import React from "react";
export const ChangePassword: NextPage<{ token: string }> = ({ token }) => {
  return (
    <div>token is {token}</div> // <-- undefined
  );
};
ChangePassword.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
  return {
    token: query.token as string,
  };
};
export default ChangePassword;
```

Comment: You don't need to use `getInitialProps`, just use [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter), e.g. `const router = useRouter(); console.log(router.query.token)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the page props to get this information:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import React from "react";

export const ChangePassword: NextPage<{ params: PageParams }> = ({ params })) => {

  const { token } = params;

  return (
    <div>token is {token}</div> // <-- undefined
  );
};
export default ChangePassword;
```